# 2 Questions 2 Radio buttons no Loading

Tags: ajax, webforms, javascript

I have a website with a webform module. It has got 2 questions with 4 radio buttons each and then a break-page so when someone clicks on one of the radio buttons, it automatically takes them to the next question. However, when someone clicks on the first questions radio button it loads the whole page and then when someone clicks on the second one, then it loads again.

I tried using a ajax page module but it doesn't work I m using this jquery code at the moment

here is the form below

http://goo.gl/bUqvZ

this is the jquery form I am using

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.form-radio').click(function() { $('#edit-next').click(); });
});
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

How do I get rid of the loading after every selection of the questions

Comment: basically, in your jQery script you are telling Drupal to simulate click on nest button. Click on next button will reload page. Works as you told it to.

Comment: yes but it reloads after every question but it will be godd if it reloads after selecting two questions

Comment: So don't call it after every click, that's all.

Comment: i have tried using .dblclick() but that only works when you press drouble in a matter of seconds while it cant be done because the person has to read the question and will take time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own jQuery. Use [Form API Ajax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) for your callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this Basic Ajax form submit example may help you.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Demo module, Basic Ajax form submit (Ajax framework).
 */

 /**
  * Implements hook_menu().
  */
function demo_menu() {
  return array(
    'demo/newsletter' => array(
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('demo_demo_form'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ),
  );
}

 /**
  * A simple newsletter subscribe form.
  */
function demo_demo_form($form, &$form_state) {
  return array(
    'email' => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Join our Newsletter'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => t('mail@example.com'),
      ),
    ),
    'submit' => array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Subscribe'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'demo_form_ajax_submit',
        'wrapper' => 'demo-demo-form',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Ajax callback function.
 */
function demo_form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // Dummy/dumb validation for demo purpose.
  if (!empty($form_state['input']['email'])) {
    return 'Subscribed !';
  }
  else {
    return $form;
  }
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/pascalduez/1517513)